# Spring MVC dispatcher issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, dispatcher

I am new to Spring MVC and I am converting my standard Web Java project. I am having a problem making the project call a controller by default instead of a JSP page. In the web project before every request was handled by a controller and this doesn't seem to be the case with Spring could anyone advise?

I am using Netbeans and my code so far is below:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Dispatcher Servlet

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.danny" />


<bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

LoginController

```
package com.spring.InternetJavaSpring.Controllers;

import com.spring.InternetJavaSpring.BusinessLogic.UserBusLog;
import static com.spring.InternetJavaSpring.BusinessLogic.UserBusLog.currentUser;
import com.spring.InternetJavaSpring.Model.Login;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="login")
public class LoginCont {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Map<String, Object>model) {
    Login user = new Login();
    model.put("loginForm", user);
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") 
        Login xLogin, BindingResult xResult, Map<String, Object>model) {

    if(xResult.hasErrors()){
        return "login";
    }

    UserBusLog ULogic = new UserBusLog();

    ULogic.Login(xLogin);

    model.put("fname", currentUser.getFName());
    model.put("lname", currentUser.getLName());

    return "home";
}
```

Any help would be a appreciated as I have spent two days on this and have got no where. Many thanks

Comment: What is the URL you are using to hit the controller and what is the error message you get?

Comment: http://localhost/SpringIJ/login is what I would like it call by default and I get a 404

Comment: did the below answer had any effect?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the controller class is not registered because the package name specified in `<context:component-scan>` seem to be incorrect. Change it as below and check if it works.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.InternetJavaSpring.Controllers" />
<context:annotation-config />
```